# Android phones for testing

Tags: java, android

I heard that for testing android application you have to test them on 2 different phones(depends of resolution) What phones are recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is a phone (Nexus S?) and a tablet if you want the most coverage.  You can, however, use the emulator to emulate phones of varying screen sizes.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest testing on a device with 'pure' Android and at least one other with a third-party overlay like HTC Sense. Sense shouldn't get in the way, but if there is some sort of incompatibility for whatever reason then it's always best to know before you release!

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Sense *shouldn't* get in the way, but it does on occasion. Especially if you're using the `WebView`.

Answer (score 2):

For UI, Android emulators are fairly robust, You should set up all possible configurations based on the table listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and test atleast once on all of them. That way you will have majority of UI issues address. After that you will need to ensure the correct API's are supported, so test on one handset having the target Android version.